# Infinite Maze of Squares with Random Thin Walls: Bounded?

Tags: probability, random-graphs, graph-connectivity

A finite maze is generated as follows: A N×N grid of squares, where N is odd, and each border between two squares, or between a square and the outside of the N×N grid, has a p% chance of being a wall. The start is in the middle, and the goal is to get out of the N×N zone.

Let f(N,p) be the probability that there is a way out of the N×N maze with p% walls. What is the limit of f(N,p) as N goes to infinity? When is the limit 0?

**Modified versions of the problem:**

Walls are full squares, so squares in the grid have a p% chance to be wall tiles (and if the start is a wall tile then it is automatically inescapable).

Higher dimensional mazes.

Both.

Comment: This is an interesting problem! Did you come up with it, or did you find it somewhere?

Comment: I came up with it a while ago when I was thinking about the backrooms. But maybe someone else has thought about it before me.